# XFS File Not Displayed in Login System Info

Tags: 20.04, xfs

I have upgraded a file system from EXT4 to XFS.
When I log onto the server the EXT4 file system utilization information is displayed however the XFS file system information is not.

How do I correct this so that the XFS file system information is also displayed.

Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

when you log on the server, the scripts located in /etc/update-motd.d are executed (in alphabetically order), and their output displayed.

if you already have a script doing this job, you can :

- write your own script
- ask the script's package maintainer for a fix

(I've just check on my Ubuntu 20.04, and I don't have such script)

hope this helps

Comment: The script that appears to be executed is as follows.
I'm not a script writer, therefore I don't know what to do to get xfs file systems to report.
 /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo